# Is it possible to change GMSPolygon fillColor from the didTapOverlay method?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Is it possible to change a `GMSPolygon` **.fillColor** property from the `didTapOverlay` `GMSMapViewDelegate` delegation method? This is the delegation method:

`func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapOverlay overlay: GMSOverlay)`

my problem is that `GMSPolygon` inherits from `GMSOverlay` and the overlay doesn't have a fillColor property. The result I would like to achieve is to change the color of the polygon when the user taps it

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a simple (single line) way to do that. Since `GMSPolygon` is a subclass of `GMSOverlay` we can cast him to be a GMSPolygon object, the delegate method will continue to work normally and it will treat it as a GMSPolygon object, changing it's `.fillColor` property.

Here's the code:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapOverlay overlay: GMSOverlay) {
    /* Here we cast the GMSOverlay to be a GMSPolygon */
    let overlay = overlay as! GMSPolygon

    overlay.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    /* Now the color of the polygon has changed on the map */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same situation before (I used Objective-C for that time).

My solution was that generating unique IDs(random strings or number), then set them to the title property of each GMSPolygons.

The below code is written by Objective-C, but you might understand

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapOverlay:(GMSOverlay *)overlay {
  NSString *overlayClass = NSStringFromClass([overlay class]);
  if ([overlayClass isEqualToString:@"GMSPolygon"] ||
      [overlayClass isEqualToString:@"GMSPolyline"] ||
      [overlayClass isEqualToString:@"GMSCircle"] ||
      [overlayClass isEqualToString:@"GMSGroundOverlay"]) {
    [self triggerOverlayEvent:@"overlay_click" id:overlay.title];  // <-- here
  }
}
```

Of course, you need to manage all polygons (and others) with the generated IDs by yourself.